# Problem with Bootstrap in nodeJS and expressJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, express-handlebars

I use Bootstrap 4 in nodejs and express with handlebars template engine, the design is work as well but bootstrap.js not work with me in my project
I take navbar code from the bootstrap website and past it in header.hbs file now I face a problem with the dropdown list in navbar when I click on dropdown do not work ( inform that I insert bootstrap CSS file, jquery file, and bootstrap.js file and I try bootstrap CDN at the same problem dropdown not work ) can you help me about this?
Thanks
[image]

The code in app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const expressHbs = require('express-handlebars')

var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.engine(
  "hbs",
  expressHbs({
    defaultLayout: "layout",
    extname: ".hbs",
  })
);
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

mongoose.connect(
  "mongodb://localhost/shopping-cart",
  { useUnifiedTopology: true, useNewUrlParser: true },
  (error) => {
    if (error) {
      console.log("the error from mongoose" + error);
    }
    console.log("connecting to DB Shopping Cart...");
  }
);
app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

The code in layout.hbs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>{{title}}</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.9.0/css/all.min.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito:wght@600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />

  </head>
  <body>
    {{> header}}
    <div class="container">
      {{{body}}}
    </div>






        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The code in header.hbs

```
          <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
        <div class="container-fluid ">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse d-flex justify-content-end" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                  <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i>
                  Shopping-Cart
                </a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                  <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
                  User-Management
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
                  <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else 
                    here</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
```

The console in the browser
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sbWrN.png)

Comment: Please include the actual code rather than an image, and also any console or network errors if there are any.

Comment: Thank you for your reply , I edit the post and include the code

Comment: @WillTaylor
please help me if you can

Answer (score 0):

Run `npm install bootstrap` and add in app.js below routes:

```js
app.use(
    // Where "/scripts/js" is a folder into "public"
    "/scripts/js", 
    express.static(
        path.join(__dirname, "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js")
    )
);
```

Cheers!